# angular output decorator is not working giving the error

Tags: javascript, angular

demo.Parent.html

```
<p>demo-parent works!</p>
<app-demo-child (property)="parentFunction($event)"  ></app-demo-child>
```

demo.parent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo-parent',
  templateUrl: './demo-parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo-parent.component.css']
})
export class DemoParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }


  display : any;

  parentFuction(event: any){

    this.display=event;
    console.log(this.display);

  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

demo.child.html

```
<p>demo-child works!</p>
```

demo.child.component.ts

```
export class DemoChildComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() property = new EventEmitter<String>();

 value : string="angualr";

  constructor() { 

  }


  senndData(){
    this.property.emit( this.value);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

.

```
Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1
```

WARNING in ./node_modules/protractor/built/configParser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'coffee-script' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/built'

WARNING in ./node_modules/protractor/built/configParser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'coffeescript' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/built'

WARNING in ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/source-map-support'

WARNING in ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/source-map-support'

ERROR in ./node_modules/saucelabs/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib-cov/SauceLabs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/saucelabs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/built'
ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/debugger.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/built'
ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/bpRunner.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/built'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net'
ERROR in ./node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/webdriver_logger.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/fs.realpath'
1mERROR in ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/logger.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/built'
ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders'
ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/local.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders'
ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cli/logger.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cli'
ERROR in ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/rimraf'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/edge.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/ie.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/opera.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/phantomjs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/profile.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/extension.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/devmode.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net'

Comment: Please share more details like HTML where you use  property.

Comment: @sagar can you show how you called `DemoChildComponent` component in html

Comment: I have updated the code now look at it

Comment: @sagar-k update my answer Please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try importing `EventEmitter` from Angular instead of from `protractor`:

`import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: Hi Vijay Import error has been cleared but now I not able to get data from a child

Comment: must be same type parent and child both component

Answer (score 1):

```
//value : string="sam";
```

-> this.value is not defined, as it´s only a comment. Is that the case in your real code too?